# How to show picker on item selected in MasterPage?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, master-pages, picker

I installed Xamarin.Forms.InputKit in NuGet and trying to show picker on certain selected item in MasterPage.

```
xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:agroNet.AppResource;assembly=agroNet"

<Picker Title="{i18n:Translate ChangeLanguage}">
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>Srpski</x:String>
        <x:String>Engleski</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

Currently, MasterPageDetail looks like this
(For now I want it to be blank):
[image]

So, on select item "Change language"
[image]

I want to show Picker, like this:
[image]

Comment: Why not use the drop-down list to select a language, which is more convenient.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Dropdownl list is equivalent to picker...

Comment: Yeah , this's right.Maybe drop-down list will be relatively easy to implement.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFTI did it using DisplayActionSheet.
`DisplayActionSheet(AppResource.LocalizationResource.ChangeLanguage, "", "", AppResource.LocalizationResource.SerbianLanguage, AppResource.LocalizationResource.EnglishLanguage);`

Comment: Great,thanks for solution, I will try it.You can share it as an answer :)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Just added. You wellcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MasterPage I have `ListView_ItemSelected` method for navigation over pages...
So, solution is to add these lines in code

```
if (item.Id == 4)
{
    DisplayActionSheet(LocalizationResource.ChangeLanguage, "", "", LocalizationResource.SerbianLanguage, LocalizationResource.EnglishLanguage);
}
```

Using tihs, there is no need of any modification of xaml file.